# SqlGrammarException Incorrect syntax near 'limit' sybase grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, sybase

I'm trying to access a sybase database and getting an

```
SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near `limit`
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near 'limit'.

at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source) ~[jconnect-6.0.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.nextResult(Unknown Source) ~[jconnect-6.0.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.ResultGetter.nextResult(Unknown Source) ~[jconnect-6.0.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) ~[jconnect-6.0.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) ~[jconnect-6.0.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(Unknown Source) ~[jconnect-6.0.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[jconnect-6.0.jar:na]
at com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[jconnect-6.0.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
... 135 common frames omitted
```

I have the following domain class:

```
class MyDomain {
    String name

    static mapping = {
         datasource 'sybase'
    }
}
```

When I call `MyDomainClass.findByName('FooBar')` I get the exception.

I know that in sybase there is no keyword limit, but since GORM creates the corresponding sql statement I don't know how to fix this.

The following hibernate dialect is used:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect
```

DataSource configuration:

```
dataSources:
   dataSource:
     pooled: true
     jmxExport: true
     driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
     dialect: org.postgresql.PostgreSQLDialect
     username: ${database.user}
     password: ${database.password}
   sybase:
     driverClassName: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
     dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseASE15Dialect
     username: ${database.sybase.user}
     password: ${database.sybase.password}
     url: jdbc:sybase:Tds:${database.sybase.url}:${database.sybase.port}/db
```

URL of postgres is inside of the different environments (dev, test and production), sybase is fix for all stages so I configured it there.

EDIT:

As I just found out it isn't a sybase problem, it has something to do with the second datasource I'm using which is a Postgres database, but I still don't know what exactly causes this problem.

Using only the sybase datasource solves the issue.

EDIT2:

I solved the problem. There's a bug inside Grails 3.0.1 (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9011) which got fixed in 3.0.2

Comment: Attach postgres configurations and exceptions you are encountering. Make sure you use sourceforge dialect for postgres.

Comment: Hi Ejaz, I added the dataSource configuration, I only get errors when calling the dynamic queries on the sybase domain classes (only one working is findById). I've checked that sybase is working by copying the sybase classes into a new project with only one dataSource.

Comment: ```As I just found out it isn't a sybase problem, it has something to do with the second datasource I'm using which is a Postgres database, but I still don't know what exactly causes this problem.
```
What were you referring to in these lines?

Comment: I've copied the sybase domain classes into a new project with only the sybase datasource and the same query worked without an issue.